# How to dynamically define arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I need to dynamically create arrays in runtime based on count. For example if I have an source array `sourcearr = ['arr1','arr2','arr3','arr4']`, the count of the elements of sourcearr is 4 i.e. `var count = sourcearr.length`, I need something like:

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    //define 4 dynamic arrays here
    //basically create arr1 = [],arr2 =[], arr3=[],arr4=[]; dynamically.
}
```

Is there any way to create and then access these arrays dynamically?

Comment: you can with `eval`, but generally you can just use multi-dimensional array instead

Comment: `eval` is never a good choise! `eval is evil`

Comment: Please specify why do you think you need this? Normaly such a wish is pointing out a design problem.

Comment: Inside your sourcearr the values of the indices could be arrays instead of a string.  Then when you iterate over the arrays you could dynamically set their values.  If you need the sourcearr to be strings, I would just create a new `dynamicarr` and set the values there.

Comment: you would be better with a multiple dimension array or an object that holds arrays

Comment: You can set them on the window object, but the better thing to do would be store them in a locally defined object. `window[sourcearr[i]] = []`, or `var myArrs = {}; for(...) { myArrs[sourcearr[i]] = [] }`

Comment: @JoshuaK I am trying to parse a .csv file. The .csv file contains column headers and columnar data. My goal is to be able to read the first row of the csv, count the number of headers, create an array for each header and store the values of the columns in the arrays. I need it to be dynamic because the number of columns in the source csv is dynamic.

Comment: In my logic, I would create an object and then add those columns as properties of my object.

Comment: follow the suggestion of using an 2d array. Just define a variable as an array and inside this array you define an array for each column.

Comment: Can you please provide an example @Lucas_Santos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but that should work like you want it.

```
var count = sourcearr.length;

var container = [];

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var newArray = new Array();
  newArray = ['x' , i]; // just example values
  container.push(newArray);
}

console.log(container[0][1]); // access the second value of the first array
```

So in general it's just a multidimensional array

Comment: Multidimensional array working perfectly! Thank you everyone for your help.